# How to run the samples of flutter with syncfusion flutter control panel

Tags: flutter, github, flutter-dependencies, syncfusion, git-tower

I have downloaded Syncfusion, I want to run flutter code in it, but I am not getting how to run code in it, and how I can get sample code from it. If anyone knows please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Priyam Srinivasta,

After installing our Syncfusion control build, open the control panel and click on the Explore Demo Source button as in the following screenshot, there you can find the code example. And also you can view our samples from below page.

https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-examples

[Control Panel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MURde.png)

It will navigate you to the demo folder which is named **Sample Browser**.

In your IDE(Say Vs code/Android studio), kindly navigate to that location, and by default, it prompts you to get packages, click on it or you can manually get the packages by using any one of the following commands in the terminal,

**'flutter packages get' or 'flutter pub get'**

After getting the packages successfully, you can run the samples in your IDE to view our samples.

Thanks,
Dharanitharan. P